# appendChild performance problems in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I am having an issue with speed in chrome with an appendchild line in javascript.  This seems to be running fine in firefox and chrome, but not Chrome is extremely slow.  I am only trying to add one element on a button click.  The page already has well over 10,000 elements, but I'm not sure if that is part of the issue.

Just to go over things I have looked at. I have looked up documentfragment, and attempted to implement that, but was getting the same results.  And from what I gather, documentfragment usually improves performance when you are adding A LOT of elements to the dom, not just one.  (Feel free to correct me if I am wrong on this assumption).  I also ran the timeline in Chrome and found that that the "Layout" is taking 11.91s to load and seems to be getting stuck on the appendchild line.  I have commented the line in question below.

As I mentioned before I had tried documentfragment with the no improvement, so this is my original code.

```
function addYr() { 
         divArray = document.getElementById('acct_sect').getElementsByTagName("div");
         divRow = document.createElement("div");
         divRow.id = "acct_row_" + (divArray.length);

         var yr  = document.createElement("input");
         yr.type= "text";
         yr.id= "yr_" + divArray.length;
         yr.name= "yr_" + divArray.length;
         yr.setAttribute("onkeydown", "TabNext(this,'down',2); return justNums(event);");
         yr.setAttribute("onkeyup", "TabNext(this,'up',2,this.form.fnd_)");
         yr.maxLength = 2;   
         yr.className = "c1";
         yr.setAttribute("onchange", "buildAccountMultiRow(this)");
         yr.value = "";

         divRow.appendChild(yr);


    //line that is taking a while
    document.getElementById('acct_sect').appendChild(divRow);
}
```

Comment: It would probably be much faster if you didn't set the event handlers as string attributes (which must be evalled) but as standard functions (ie `yr.onkeydown=function(){...`) and it would be even better to use the same function for all elements.

Comment: @dystoy, thanks for your comment.  I will try this.  This is probably just my dumb reading comprehension, but what do you mean when you say "use the same function for all elements".

Comment: I mean your string is the same. So simply define a function outside of the loop `function myFunction(){TabNext(this,'down',2); return justNums(event)}` and do `yr.onkeydown=myFunction` when appending.

Comment: Are you adding the new rows in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

The large number of elements is most likely to blame, but here's something to try:

- `getElementsByTagName` returns a live list, that must be updated every time it changes. Instead, try this:

  ```
  divArray = document.getElementById('acct_sect').children;
  ```
- If you don't use the `id` attribute for anything, remove that.
- If you can rearrange some code on the server, try:

  ```
  yr.name = "yr[]";
  ```

  Then on the server you will get (for instance in PHP) `$_POST['yr']` as an array containing the values.
- If you can do both of the above two items, then you will find that you don't even need `divArray` any more, and can just get rid of that entirely, which should save a LOT of time.
- Try changing how you handle events. Instead of assigning three event handlers to every single element, assign a single one to the container.

  ```
  var ac = document.getElementById('acct_sect');
  ac.onkeydown = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
      if( t.nodeName == "INPUT") {
          tabNext(t,'down',2);
          return justNums(e);
      }
  };
  ac.onkeyup = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
      if( t.nodeName == "INPUT") {
          tabNext(t,'up',2,t.form.fnd_);
      }
  };
  ac.onchange = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
      if( t.nodeName == "INPUT") {
          buildAccountMultiRow(t);
      }
  };
  ```